# Validate all select option text in created divs dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help. I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MetCastle/2Lgumtp8/) , as you can see, clone the original div with new name and with the text selected, and now I want to validate that created selects, if their selected option is "select" alert the user and focus in that select,

I think in something like this, check the divs that name start with "newDiv" and selects inside with text equal to "Select"

```
$('button#validate').live('click', function() {

var wrong = $('div[name^="newDiv"] select option').filter(':selected').text();

if ( wrong == "Select" )
{
    alert("Please select an option"); 
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
}


});
```

I hope you understand what I mean to say, thanks.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, use `.click()` or  `.on("click"` instead.

Comment: The code in your jsFiddle is completely different than the code in your OP.

Comment: you don't have Select as an option. can you check your fiddle, you might have to change the base version for the fiddle

Comment: In your fiddle your new divs **do not** have a `name` attribute so `div[name^="newDiv"]` will not do anything.

Comment: At the moment your question and JSFiddle have too many inconsistencies to make it worth anyone's time sorting it out. Please read your own question and JSFiddle, adjust one, or the other (or both) and come back with your changes. Then we can help.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, i'm already update thhe fiddle in the post.

Comment: Which div do you want validated? All, or the last? This still makes little sense (from a UI design point of view).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie all selects except the original. Thanks.

Comment: OK... Answer below... it tests each selection and aborts if one is "Select" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2Lgumtp8/3/

Various fixes:

- Then new divs had no id, so I changed the filter to use ids.
- I iterate all matching selected values. if one is wrong, abort there.
- I remove highlight of all selects prior to check.
- I focus the the closest parent select of the wrong option
- I highlight the closest parent select of the wrong option

  $(document).ready(function () {

  ```
  var counter = 2;

  $("input#clone").click(function () {
      //Let's make a copy to work with
      var originalDiv = $("div#old");
      var cloneDiv = originalDiv.clone();
      //Renaming cloneDiv
      cloneDiv.attr('id', 'newDiv' + counter);
      //Renaming inputs in  cloneDiv
      $("[name='id']", cloneDiv).attr('name', 'id' + counter);
      $("[name='email']", cloneDiv).attr('name', 'email' + counter);
      $("[name='emails']", cloneDiv).attr('name', 'emails' + counter);
      //Value first textfield
      $("[name='id" + counter + "']", cloneDiv).val(+counter);

      //Value Select
      $("[name='email" + counter + "']", cloneDiv).val($("[name='email'] option:selected", originalDiv).val());
      $("[name='emails" + counter + "']", cloneDiv).val($("[name='emails'] option:selected", originalDiv).val());

      //Append to originalDiv container whatever it is...
      originalDiv.parent().append(cloneDiv);
      //OR Append to body after old div
      //$('.old:last').after(cloneDiv);
      //Increment counter
      counter++;
  });

  $("input#remove").click(function (e) {
      if (counter > 2) {
          $('#newDiv' + (counter - 1)).remove();
          counter--;
      }
  });

  $('#validate').click(function () {
      $('div[id^="newDiv"] select').css("background-color", "");
      $('div[id^="newDiv"] select option').filter(':selected').each(function () {
          var select = $(this);
          if (select.text() == "Select") {
              alert("Please select an option");
              select.closest('select').focus().css("background-color", "red");
              return false;
          }
      });
  });
  ```

  });

Comment: Awesome men ! That's exactly what I need.

Thanks so much !